# Formatting a '$' dollar sign to an SQL Selection Statement with SUM() in it?

Tags: sql, oracle, formatting, currency, to-char

I'm trying to format a '$' dollar sign to column "c" which is the SUM of all rows of two other columns multiplied together.  I first turn it into a character as follows:

```
   SELECT TO_CHAR(SUM(a * b)) AS "c"
   FROM table1;
```

which works fine, but when I format it by adding 'L9,999.99' formatter it gives an error:

```
   SELECT TO_CHAR(SUM(a * b, 'L9,999.99') AS "c"
   FROM table1;
```

So I tried doing a CAST:

```
   SELECT TO_CHAR(CAST(SUM(a * b) AS NUMERIC(10,2)) AS "c"
   FROM table1;
```

But nothing is working.

How can I add a '$' dollar sign to a column with a SUM() function using TO_CHAR and/or CAST?

For reference, my intended output is to turn:

```
    C
    10
    10.05
    11.50
```

into

```
    C
    $10
    $10.05
    $11.50
```

Comment: and you won't tell us which error is raised? Does this format work if you format literal numbers? Does the sum work without formatting? What is the type of the involved columns?

Comment: Does it work if you use the same number of opening and closing brackets?

Comment: All my data type are number(10, 2).  The error raised is: "ORA-01722: invalid number"

Comment: I don't believe that this is the error number you get

Comment: With the extra closing parenthesis this works fine as a standalone query; so where and how are you running it, and is it actually part of a larger query that (explicitly or implicitly) tries to treat the string you've generated as a number again? Try to create [an MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that creates and populates a table and generates this error when queried - something and we can run in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding the comment of JJJ: There was a paranthese missing, the following should work:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(SUM(a * b), 'L9,999.99') AS "c"
FROM table1;
```

The  statement

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(SUM(a * b, 'L9,999.99') AS "c"
FROM table1;
```

will raise a compile time error:

```
 ORA-00909: invalid number of arguments
```

Comment: Oh sorry, that was just a typo on my part in typing this question.  My original SQL statement did have that bracket and it's still not working which is why I'm asking here.

Comment: @5120bee: So how do you want to proceed? Do you think that somebody reads your question, then reads this comment, use it to reconstruct the statement that you claim you have executed, then finds your other comment with the error message, realizes (see Alex Poole's comment to your post) that this isn't yet the statement you executed, guesses the real statement you executed and then posts a useful solution?